# How can I place the cursor inside of my image ||| Pygame error |||

Tags: python, pygame

Here is the code I am having issues with. I am creating a small basic mouse tracking "game" in pygame however, though I have added /2 next to the width and height... the mouse will not go to the center. Here is the code. What am I doing wrong

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

bg_image = "bg.jpg"
mouse_image = "superball.jpg"

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 1000),0,32)

background = pygame.image.load(bg_image).convert()
mouse_c = pygame.image.load(mouse_image).convert_alpha()

while True:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
              pygame.quit()
              sys.exit()
  screen.blit(background, (0,0))

  x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
  x != mouse_c.get_width()/2 
  y != mouse_c.get_height()/2

  screen.blit(mouse_c,(x,y))

  pygame.display.update()
```

Ignore the indent mistakes. That was a copy and paste error

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you have written x != mouse_c.get_width()/2 instead of x = mouse_c.get_width()/2
Same with the y.

Simply remove the not '!' symbol from those two lines and it should work. x != mouse_c.get_width()/2 is a comparison statement, the whole thing will evaluate to true or false. x and y will remain unchanged, so when you use them later they are still the original values.